# Is it possible for me to return a printf statement from a function? C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a printf statement to be returned from a function but it is giving me a compile error.

```
string calculation(int choice)
{
    float input1, input2;

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        cout << "You have chosen Addition.\n";
        cout << "Enter first number: ";
        cin >> input1;
        cout << "Enter second number: ";
        cin >> input2;
        float add = addition(input1, input2);
        return printf("%.1f + %.1f = %.1f\n", input1, input2, add);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `snprintf`? Or `std::ostringstream` and its `str` function?

Comment: `printf` returns an integer with its value telling you how much characters got written to `stdout`.

Comment: @chris: surely you mean `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: When you say return a printf statement what do you mean? A pointer to function that will reprint that string or the string that printf will print. As for your code printf returns an int not a string so the return statement will be invalid.

Comment: @Gibby i want it to return a formatted string like the printf would, so when the calculation() function is called in the main function, it would print that formatted string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf()` just formats output according to the format string and sends it to the standard output (`stdout`). There is no way to intercept this output and return it as a `std::string`. You can construct a `std::string` using either `snprintf()` or `std::ostringstream`:

```
char buffer[100];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.1f + %.1f = %.1f\n", input1, input2, add);
return buffer;
```

or

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1)
    << input1 << " + " << input2 << " = " << add << '\n';
return out.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf()` is an int method therefore you cannot return it as it gives an int value. It will return the amount of characters written to `stdout`. Either change your method to `int calculation(int choice)` or format your statement to a string and return that, while printing it in the method calling this one.

Comment: It actually returns an integer, but same idea.

Comment: Thanks, fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` returns an int not a string. Simply search for the c++ documentation in google. Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)